# Is there a way to add extra identifier class if you're viewing Partial Design (header in my case) on Experience Editor?

Tags: sxa, experience-editor

I'm currently doing a specific styling for header partial design that will only apply when you viewed it on Experience Editor (EE). I'm aware of the `on-page-editor` class on body tag but I need extra identifier to prevent the styles to apply in pages (still in EE) wherein the partial design is included. Is there a way to do that?

```
// This will apply to partial design but will also affect header in pages (in Experience Editor)
.on-page-editor {
    header {
      position: static;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check with class: "experience-editor" . I noticed on experience editor body html tag has class "experience-editor"

Comment: Thanks, @VladIobagiu! The problem with that (on-page-editor class) is it also applies to page that has header in it. I'm trying to narrow down the specific styling to just partial design itself when viewed in Experience Editor.

Comment: @tyronedee Did you try to add a partial-design experience-editor-specific class manually? For example, check the current rendering item template. If it created from a partial design template/any template that you need then add a CSS class in the block that you want to style.